# Didn't understand the output of this code

Tags: c, pointers

What will be the output of the following program if the address of variable 'a' is 66553?

```
#include<stdio.h>
include<conio.h>
int main() {
  int a=10;
  void *k;
  k=&a;
  k++;
  printf("\n%u", k);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Why output of the above code is not 66554?

Why it will generate an error?

Comment: void* isn't guaranteed to be of size 1. some compilers allow it to be 1, others crash.

Comment: You have two problems" (1) you're printing the pointer value using `%u`, which isn't guaranteed to work (especially in 64-bit or other "mixed" models).  Use `%p` instead.  (2) You're trying to do arithmetic on a void pointer.  You really want to use `char *`, or in this case maybe `int *`.  (And if you compare the difference between incrementing an `char *` versus an `int *`, you should learn something.)

Comment: if you need it to be incremented by 1, use `uint8_t *` type for your pointer.

Comment: Only GCC allows arithmetic on `void *` (and probably Clang for GCC compatibility).  The C standard does not allow arithmetic on `void *`.